# Async not working on controller's abstract super class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `BaseRestController` class that Rest controllers extend. It has a method that I want to run asynchronously.

```
public abstract class BaseRestController {
    ...

    @Async("someThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void someAsyncTask() {
        ...
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController extends BaseRestController {
    ...

    @GetMapping("/some/path")
    public SomeEntity getSomething() {
        ...
        this.someAsyncTask();
    }        
}
```

I have enabled `Async` using annotation, implemented a method that gets `someThreadPoolTaskExecutor` *TaskExecutor* and all. If I put `@Async("someThreadPoolTaskExecutor")` on a Service's (class annotated with `@Service`) method, it works but if I do so with *someAsyncTask()* in *BaseRestController* the code won't run asynchronously. Decorating the class with *@Component* didn't work either.

[Spring guide on Async](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) didn't help either. In it's demo, it also demonstrates *Async* with service class.

While, in the process, I realized that the behavior I wanted to implement was better off delegated to a service class, I am curious as to understand why the above won't work.

I'm using *2.1.0.RELEASE* of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are couple of rules for `@Async`, you are doing the self-invocation which won't work [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

- it must be applied to public methods only
- self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

> The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. **And self-invocation doesn’t work because it bypasses the proxy** and calls the underlying method directly.