# Does @Asynchronous work in abstract class?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jakarta-ee

I've got an abstract class with abstract method

```
@Asynchronous
public abstract void runAsync();
```

I found this answer for `@Async` in Spring [Async not working on controller's abstract super class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432970/async-not-working-on-controllers-abstract-super-class-method)

Question is, will this method `runAsync` be asynchronous If I Override it in implementation? Or do I need to make `@Asynchronous` annotation only in implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations are **not inherited by default**. Annotations will be inherited only if it has `@Inherited` properties in the annotation definition. Now look at the `@Async` annotation definition :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Async
```

`Async` annotation does not have the properties  `@Inherited`, so it will not be inherited to subclass. In that case, you need to explicitly specify the `@Async` in the subclass override method to make it work. For more info please visit the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

EDIT: `javax.ejb.Asynchronous` also does not has `@Inherited` property ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html))

```
@Target(value={METHOD,TYPE})
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public @interface Asynchronous
```

So, in the case of `@Asynchronous`, the behavior in case of method override with `@Asynchronous` will be same as mentioned above.

Comment: Uh, OP is asking about `@javax.ejb.Asynchronous` not about `@org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async`.

Comment: @BalusC I was a bit confused with the link OP shared. I have updated my answer. Thanks for your suggestion.